# Scala code running on Intellij, but not on Apache Zeppelin notebook

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-zeppelin

I have developed some scala code to iterate over a java.util.ArrayList[Source], where Source is a case class with two Strings.

If I run my code on IntelliJ, it runs perfectly, when I get it to my Zeppelin Notebook it gives me an error.

My code is:

```
source_list.forEach(s => if(s.getPersonalDataFlg.equals("YES")){println(s.getPersonalDataID)})
```

The error in Apache Zeppelin is:

```
<console>:45: error: missing parameter type
```

Can someone tell me why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since older versions of Java did not have Lambda's, older versions of Scala had a totally different `Function` implementation.

Since you are using `forEach` on `ArrayList` which was added in Java 8, it indicates that you are already using a Java version later than Java 8.

After the introduction of Lambda's in Java 8, the later versions of Scala had their `Function` implementation based on Java lambda's.

Now, you `source_list` is a `java.util.ArrayList[Source]` which means that `source_list.forEach` expects a parameter of type `Consumer<? super Source>` which can be replaced by a Java lambda such as `(Source s) -> { }`.

You are providing it with following scala function,

```
s => if(s.getPersonalDataFlg.equals("YES")){println(s.getPersonalDataID)
```

This gets compiled to the appropriate lambda in case of newer Scala versions but will fail with older scala versions.

```
// this will work with Scala 2.12.x but fail with older versions
import java.util.ArrayList

val list = new ArrayList[Int]()

list.add(1)

list.forEach(i => println(i))
```

This error indicates that your Zeppelin notebook is running older versions of Scala (most likely 2.11.x or even 2.10.x)

With older versions of Scala, you have to explicitly create the `Consumer` and pass that to `forEach`

```
import java.util.ArrayList
import java.util.function.Consumer

val list = new ArrayList[Int]()

list.add(1)


val consumer: Consumer[Int] = new Consumer[Int] {
  override def accept(i: Int): Unit = println(i) 
}

list.forEach(consumer)
```

Comment: Thank you @Sarvesh